# Не работает запрос на добавление данных в БД

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

В общем, пытался найти в интернете - не вышло. Поэтому решил написать.
Встретился с такой проблемой - по нажатию на кнопку "Отправить" перезагружается страница, а в БД данные не добавляются. Сам код:

```
$ans_que = mysql_query("SELECT tick_id, ans_id, ans FROM anss WHERE tick_id IN ($tick_id)");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($ans_que);

if(isset($_POST['send_ans'])){
    if(empty($errorss)){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO anss (tick_id, ans_id, ans)
            VALUES ($tick_id, ($num_rows+1), '$_POST[ans]')");
        exit;
    }else{
        echo '<div class="form-group error">'.array_shift($errorss).'</div>';
    }
}
```

Самому мне кажется, что проблема связана с ajax. Весь этот код находится в отдельном файле, подгружаемом через ajax. HTML код, если как-то поможет:

```
<form method="POST">
    <textarea class="ans" placeholder="..." name="ans" required></textarea>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="send_ans" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ">
</form>
```

И ajax код:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "tick",
    type: "GET",
    data: "tick_id="+tickID,
    success: function(data) {
        $('.this-t').html(data);
        $('.t').hide();
        $('.this-t').show();
    }
});
```

Помогите, если не сложно, не очень разбираюсь в бэкенде

Comment: Если у тебя не `php5` то расширения `mysql_` уже нет. Также открой консоль разработчика в браузере и смотри что там происходит.

Comment: @u_mulder у меня php5

Comment: Плохо, он устарел и больше не поддерживается.

Comment: что такое $errorss ?

Comment: @splash58 массив с ошибками (например, не заполнено поле), при отсутствии ошибок происходит редирект

Answer (score 0):

Какой конкретно код подгружается через ajax? PHP?
Суть ajax чтобы при отправки формы страница НЕ перезапускалась. Если у Вас страница перезапускается после нажатия на кнопку, значит дело до ajax не доходит.
В html измените тип input na button

```
<form method="POST">
    <textarea class="ans" placeholder="..." name="ans" required></textarea>
    <input class="button" type="button" name="send_ans" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ"><!--тут-->
</form>
```

В JS добавьте обработчик на input

```
$('.button').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "https://mysite.com/dir/phpscr.php",//здесь укажите ссылку на PHP скрипт
    type: "POST",//исправьте тип на POST в ajax, либо в php используйте тоже GET
    //разницу смотрите в гугле
    data: "tick_id="+tickID,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);//для отладки 
        $('.this-t').html(data);
        $('.t').hide();
        $('.this-t').show();
    }
});
});
```

PHP

```
print_r($_POST);die();//верните JS все полученные скриптом данные для проверки.
//если всё верно удалите эту строку
$ans_que = mysql_query("SELECT tick_id, ans_id, ans FROM anss WHERE tick_id IN ($tick_id)");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($ans_que);

if(isset($_POST['send_ans'])){
    if(empty($errorss)){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO anss (tick_id, ans_id, ans)
            VALUES ($tick_id, ($num_rows+1), '$_POST[ans]')");
        exit;
    }else{
        echo '<div class="form-group error">'.array_shift($errorss).'</div>';
    }
}
```

так же используйте в php функцию [mysql_error](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-error.php) чтобы узнать подробности ошибки последнего mysql запроса

```
$insertMysl =  mysql_query("INSERT INTO anss (tick_id, ans_id, ans)
            VALUES ($tick_id, ($num_rows+1), '$_POST[ans]')");
    if(!$insertMysl) echo mysql_error($insertMysl);die();
```

Заметил что вы отправляете ajax type 'GET', а php используете POST. Измените либо там либо там, в примере выше я в обоих случаях использовал  POST

Comment: На всякий случай уточню, как всё работает. Есть страница "adm", там находится ajax код, По нажатии на элемент - содержимое, которое было до этого - скрывается, а элемент, на который было совершено нажатие - отображается. Php-код находится в другом файле и подгружается в "adm". 
Из того, что просили: 
1) Когда делаю type="button" по нажатию ничего не происходит, абсолютно ничего
2) alert(data) выводит html код из php файла 
3) print_r($_POST) выводит: Array ( )
4) mysql_error ничего не выводит

Comment: nick, я там сразу не заметил, измените print_r($_POST) на print_r($_GET);
тоже дополнил на input добавьте обработчик. 
PHP скрипт поместите в отдельный файл, в котором нет html. потому что в некотором роде html код в файле "эквивалентен" echo. php сервер его всегда будет возвращать

Comment: Вывод: Array ( [tick_id] => 1 )

Comment: ну так вы вроде больше ничего и не отправляли на PHP.
используйте следующую конструкцию в ajax data:
data: ({tickid:tickid, ans='ans', hello:'word'}),
и так далее. если в data нужно передать переменные то не забудьте сначала их определить.
например:
$('.button').click(function(){
var name = $('.ans).text();
$.ajax({//...
data:({nameuser:name, //....
});

Comment: создайте тестовые файлы, поместите html и js в один файл, php в другой, поэксперементируйте, тогда придет понимание, что вы делаете не так

Comment: используя ajax вы можете вообще удалить тег form и обращаться к полям через id или класс